# C# how to convert IEnumerable anonymous lists into data table

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ienumerable

Many solutions are available that convert lists to `DataTable` that use reflection, and that would work for converting anonymous types. However, it there are *lots* of lists of anonymous types, then performance can be an issue.

Is this the only way to create a `DataTable` from a list? Are there faster ways of doing this?

Comment: Before you work with *thousands of anonymous list* I would switch to declared types.

Comment: Sanity check: **why** would you convert a list of anonymous types to a `DataTable`? That seems a step down... `DataTable` is not usually an ideal API - regular classes are preferable in most ways. Named classes would of course be preferable to anonymous types, but *personally* I'd choose an anonymous type over `DataTable` most days of the week.

Answer (score 6):

It would absolutely be better to do this using proper named POCO/DTO/etc classes, but it can still be done. The cost of reflection can be removed by using meta-programming, ideally by using a pre-rolled library such as [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember), as shown below.

Note that the use of anonymous types has forced the use of `IList` here (rather than `IList<T>` or `List<T>` etc). The use of a generic version would be preferable, using named types. This would allow a few changes - in particular, `itemType` would be `typeof(T)`, and it would be possible to create the correct columns even for an empty table. Perhaps more importantly, it would *enforce* that the list is homogeneous, rather than having to make an assumption about that.

```
using FastMember;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = GetList();
        var table = ToTable(list);
    }
    static DataTable ToTable(IList source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var table = new DataTable();
        if (source.Count == 0) return table;

        // blatently assume the list is homogeneous
        Type itemType = source[0].GetType();
        table.TableName = itemType.Name;
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        foreach (var prop in itemType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.CanRead && prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
            {
                names.Add(prop.Name);
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }
        }
        names.TrimExcess();

        var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(itemType);
        object[] values = new object[names.Count];
        foreach (var row in source)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = accessor[row, names[i]];
            }
            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return table;
    }
    static IList GetList()
    {
        return new[] {
            new { foo = "abc", bar = 123},
            new { foo = "def", bar = 456},
            new { foo = "ghi", bar = 789},
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Mod to support nullable:  // Added Nullable support (@crokusek) - stackoverflow.com/a/23233413/538763 - @Damith
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);  This was rejected as a direct edit saying a comment would be better.

Comment: What is TypeAccessor

Comment: @ITGenius it is one of the classes in `FastMember` (linked in the text) that provides a level of optimized access over reflection via metaprogramming

Answer (score 1):

Improved on [@MarcGravell's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13153479/538763) answer to support:

1. An optional list of fields specifying which columns to keep and their order.
2. Nullable types.

   ```
   static public DataTable ToDataTable(this IList anonymousSource, List<string> keepOrderedFieldsOpt = null)
   {
       // https://stackoverflow.com/a/13153479/538763 - @MarcGravell
       // Added keepOrderedFieldsOpt, nullable types - @crokusek

       if (anonymousSource == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       if (anonymousSource.Count == 0) return table;

       // blatently assume the list is homogeneous
       Type itemType = anonymousSource[0].GetType();
       table.TableName = itemType.Name;            

       // Build up orderedColumns
       //
       List<PropertyInfo> orderedColumns;            
       if (keepOrderedFieldsOpt != null)
       {
           Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> propertiesByName = itemType.GetProperties()
               .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p);

           orderedColumns = new List<PropertyInfo>();
           List<string> missingFields = null;

           foreach (string field in keepOrderedFieldsOpt)
           {
               PropertyInfo tempPropertyInfo;
               if (propertiesByName.TryGetValue(field, out tempPropertyInfo))
                   orderedColumns.Add(tempPropertyInfo);
               else
                   (missingFields ?? (missingFields = new List<string>())).Add(field);
           }

           if (missingFields != null) 
               throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("keepOrderedFieldsOpt", "Argument keepOrderedFieldsOpt contains invalid field name(s): " + String.Join(", ", missingFields));
       }
       else
           orderedColumns = itemType.GetProperties().ToList();

       List<string> names = new List<string>();
       foreach (PropertyInfo prop in orderedColumns)
       {
           if (prop.CanRead && prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
           {
               names.Add(prop.Name);

               // Nullable support from stackoverflow.com/a/23233413/538763 - @Damith
               table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
           }
       }
       names.TrimExcess();

       TypeAccessor accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(itemType);
       object[] values = new object[names.Count];
       foreach (var row in anonymousSource)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
               values[i] = accessor[row, names[i]];

           table.Rows.Add(values);
       }
       return table;
   }
   ```